# Pre deploy script in app.json on heroku app

Tags: heroku

I want to run a script before heroku begins to try building my app and I want it to run the following command:

`"echo '//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=${npm_TOKEN}' > .npmrc"`

I've set up my `app.json` script section as follows:

```
"scripts": {
        "predeploy": "echo '//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=${npm_TOKEN}' > .npmrc",
        "postdeploy": "pg_dump -O ${STAGE_DATABASE_URL} | psql ${DATABASE_URL} && play evolutions:apply --%web"
    }
```

It would appear that my `predeploy` script does nothing. Looking on Heroku's website the only two scripts they define are `postdeploy` and `pr-predestroy` so I have no idea if `predeploy` is even something heroku will recognize. My question is, is it possible to add a script to the scripts section in `app.json` to run before a build occurs and if so what is the correct way to add it?

Answer (score 2):

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support
in particular
you can use those prefix to help solve your problems.
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#heroku-specific-build-steps